# Event delegation with Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

How would I do jQuery-style event delegation with plain JavaScript in Hammer.js? E.g.:

```
Hammer(document).on('tap', '.item', function () {
  console.log('tapped')
})
```

Is this directly possible or do I have to do the delegation myself?

Comment: Inspecting target - will **only** work if you click on element with `.item`. But if inside that `.item` there is another element and you click on that inner element - inspecting target will NOT help. you'd need to scan its parent (which is what other answers provided) -  which exactly what you wanted in your question `$.on('tap', '.item', function () {...}` . with jquery - using your code in question , you will be provided with the right info EVEN if you clicked in an inner element to `.item`

Comment: As you can see here - inspecting target will show you the button which is not `.item` http://jsbin.com/hobenunale/1/edit?html,js,output - while jquery does show you the delegeated element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to inspect the `target` of the Event object that's passed into your handler.

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RaxWN/).

Comment: This is not what OP wanted.

Comment: @Royi, really? Because he accepted this answer...*4 years ago*

Comment: Does it matter ? I needed to use `Hammer(document).on('tap', '.item', function () {
  console.log('tapped')
})` - And target was not a helper :-)

Comment: As you can see here - inspecting target will show you the button which is not `.item` http://jsbin.com/hobenunale/1/edit?html,js,output - while jquery does show you the delegeated element.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following function to test if the target is a delegate.

```
function _getDelegate(selector, target, currentTarget) {

   var delegate = null;

   while (target && target != currentTarget) {
      delegate = $(target).filter(selector)[0];
      if (delegate) 
         return delegate;
      target = target.parentNode;
   }

   return delegate;

}
```

I'm using the jquery filter because I use it a lot and with some more complex selectors.

Usage:

```
var delegationSelector = ".child";
$element.hammer()
$element.on("tap", function handler(event){
   var delegate = _getDelegate(delegationSelector, event.target, event.currentTarget);
   if(delegate){ // or if(!delegate) return;
      // Your handler code
   }
});
```

This won't work with all selectors, but I'd say it's better than André's in that it will still work if your "target" has child elements. E.g.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="text">Test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

André's will fail here because `target` is the `[div.text]` and doesn't have your class.

For the above usage of _getDelegate, lets' say `$element = $("#parent")`. If you tapped the word "Test" `event.target` would be `[div.text]` (where you tapped) and `event.currentTarget` would be `[div.parent]` (where the handler is registered). When you called `_getDelegate` with these parameters, you would receive `[div.child]` and know that you should run your handler code.

For a pure JS version, you'd want something like this, where you loop up through the parents looking to see if you hit anything.

```
var delegate;
var target = e.target; // e.g. Inner div
var currentTarget = e.currentTarget // e.g. #parent

while(target && target != currentTarget){
   if(target.className.indexOf('child')!=-1){
      delegate = target;
      break;
   }
   target = target.parentNode;
}

if( delegate ) {
   console.log('delegated tap received');
}
```

There are still plenty of flaws with this. The whole indexof className is a bad idea because classes can be sub-strings of one another e.g. "myClass" and "myClass2". Also, my code makes the assumption that all of your subelements are positioned within their parents.

Comment: Nice, but a usage example for your `_isDelegate` method would be helpful, and/or documentation of the parameters. Also, wouldn't `_getDelegate` be a more accurate name as it doesn't return a boolean? :)

Comment: Thanks. I added a usage example that just uses the jquery on handler though it's good that you've added on using hammer's on(). 

I've change the function name too. I'm fairly sure it was isDelegate because when I wrote it, I wasn't actual using element in the handler. When I wanted the element it was an easy change to make it return the element, but forgot to change the function name.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Jools' answer, here is what I've come up with. I didn't bother with a pure-JS solution--in fact, this is intended for use with a `Backbone.View`, but is easily adaptable to other situations.

It will stop climbing the node tree when it reaches the View's root element (`this.el`). Starting from the target identified by the HammerJS event, it will seek the first element matching the specified selector, and return `undefined` if no such element is found.

To use in a non-Backbone environment, just pass in a reference to the limiting/containing element as a 3rd argument (as in Jools' solution) and use it to replace `this.el`.

```
/**
 * @param {Node}target - the target of the received event
 * @param {String}selector - any jQuery-compatible selector
 */
getEventDelegate: function (target, selector) {
     var delegate;
     while (target && target != this.el) {
        delegate = $(target).filter(selector)[0];
        if (delegate) {
           return delegate;
        }
        target = target.parentNode;
     }
     return undefined;
  }
```

If you have an `onTap` callback function, it might look something like this:

```
/**
 * @param {Event}ev
 */
onTap: function (ev) {
   var target = this.getEventDelegate(ev.target, "#desiredTarget");
   if (target) {
      // TODO something with the target...
   }
}
```

And to hook it all up, you'd want something like this...

```
this._hammer = new Hammer(this.el);
this._hammer.on('tap', _.bind(this.onTap, this));
```

(and don't forget to call `this._hammer.destroy()` when your view is destroyed!)

Comment: Strange but OP accepted an answer which doesn't solve its issue. Target is not the same as delegated event's element

Answer (score -1):

Continuing @Lambarr's solution  - Typescript:

```
private delegateBind(rootElement:Node,e, selector:string, handler: (target:any) => any)
  {

    let target=e.target;
    let o = {

      getEventDelegate: function ()
      {
        var delegate;

        while (target && target != rootElement)
        {
          delegate = jQuery(target).filter(selector)[0];
          if (delegate)
          {
            return delegate;
          }

          target = target.parentNode;
        }
        return undefined;
      }

    };

     target = o.getEventDelegate();
    if (target)
    {
      handler(target);
    }
  }
```

Usage :

```
private registerDocumentclick()
  {

     Hammer(this.document).on('tap', e =>
        this.delegateBind(this.document,e,'.article', (elm) => console.log(elm.classList))

    );
  }
```