# Long press (hold) with jquery hammer.js 2 and event delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js, event-delegation

I recently upgraded to hammer.js 2 and one of the first things a I noticed was that "hold" has been replaced with "press".

My old code worked fine with event delegation, but switching to press only seems to work when I put it on a specific element.

Note: I use hammer.js through the jquery plugin

### Hammer.js 1

```
$(element).hammer().on("hold",callback);
```

Works fine

```
$(rootElement).hammer().on("hold",".elementSelector",callback);
```

Works fine

### Hammer.js 2

This

```
$(element).hammer().on("press",callback);
```

works fine, while this

```
$(rootElement).hammer().on("press",".elementSelector",callback);
```

does not. The callback is never fired.

Comment: did you get this to work? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Not exactly, but I'm currently using a work around where I just put the listener on the root element, without a delegation selector and use my own function to figure out whether the inner element that triggered the event was one of (or the child of one of) the desired elements. I gave the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25450384/514793)

Answer (score 5):

Hammer events have been simplified for speed in the new version. To reenable event delegation, just add domEvents:true as an option:

```
$(rootElement).hammer({domEvents:true}).on("press",".elementSelector",callback);
```