# How do you delegate events in hammer.js version 2.0?

Tags: jquery, hammer.js

In hammer.js v1.x (with jquery plugin) you could delegate events like this:

```
$('ul').hammer().on("touch", "li", callback);
```

With this syntax, you could attach the event listener to the `ul` instead of the individual `li` elements that you wanted to listen to. This would allow you to dynamically add `li` elements to the `ul` without reattaching event listeners.

However I can't figure out how to do it in Hammer v2.0. (I've changed `touch` to `tap` per the new syntax).

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way, but you could for sure check the event object in the callback and compare the targets `tagName` against `li` then perform it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For speed, hammer now fires paired-down events by default. However, you can reenable event delegation by turning on the domEvents setting like this:

```
$('ul').hammer({domEvents:true}).on("tap", "li", callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question with no answer ([Long press (hold) with jquery hammer.js 2 and event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134649/long-press-hold-with-jquery-hammer-js-2-and-event-delegation)).

I ended up checking event target. It's a bit annoying because it means you can't use some of the fancier selectors with extra work, but if you run up from the target to your root/parent, you should catch what you want. You can't just look at the li, if you put other elements inside of that li, because then the target may well be a div.

I use this function:

```
function _isDelegate(selector, target, currentTarget) {

   var delegate = null;

   while (target && target != currentTarget) {
      delegate = $(target).filter(selector)[0];
      if (delegate) 
         return delegate;
      target = target.parentNode;
   }

   return delegate;

}
```

`selector` is your delegation selector e.g. "li". 
`target` is the element given in the event object under the same name. If you touched right it should be the li or one of its children.
`currentTarget` is the parent/root element where you actually registered the listener.

The return will be `null` if you didn't touch a li, so you can ignore the event, or it will be the li element, if you touched on or inside of it.

Comment: Thanks Jools, this was helpful. I actually rewrote all my code like this before discovering that the actual fix was really simple.